# How to use subxt in yew.rs front-end app

Tags: rust, substrate-front-end, subxt, rust-ipfs

Here is test demo, but always fail to run.

- `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
yew = { version = "0.20.0", features = ["csr"] }
gloo = "0.8.0"
wasm-bindgen-futures = "0.4.32"
subxt = { version="0.27.0", default-features = false, features = ["jsonrpsee-web"] }
```

- `main.rs`

```rust
use gloo::console::log;
// use sp_keyring::AccountKeyring;
use subxt::{OnlineClient, PolkadotConfig};
use wasm_bindgen_futures;
use yew::prelude::*;

#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "metadata.scale")]
pub mod polkadot {}

#[function_component(App)]
fn app() -> Html {
    wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
        let api = OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::new().await.unwrap();
        log!("hello world");
    });
    html! {
      <>
          <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline bg-slate-100">{"Hello world!"}</h1>
      </>
    }
}

fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

**The problem is `#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "metadata.scale")] pub mod polkadot {}` always throw an error**

```
error: Failed to decode metadata: Could not decode `RuntimeMetadataPrefixed.1`:
           Could not decode `RuntimeMetadata`, variant doesn't exist
```

I think I followed the steps exactly in the official documentation

1. Build a local blockchain
2. run `cargo install subxt-cli`
3. run `subxt metadata -f bytes > metadata.scale`

- What steps I forgot and need to do?
- By the way, I find if I don't specify the subxt as `subxt = { version="0.27.0", default-features = false, features = ["jsonrpsee-web"] }` in my `Cargo.toml`, it seem like impossible to work with `Yew.rs`.And if i set subxt as `subxt = { version="0.27.0", default-features = false, features = ["jsonrpsee-web"] }` in my `Cargo.toml`, the `OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::new().await.unwrap();` also throw error.

```
no function or associated item named `new` found for struct `OnlineClient` in the current scope
```

Can someone answer this question for me?

Comment: I still think there are too many sub-questions in this question. Can you make it more clear? Maybe you can open a single question to ask why the subxt can not decode metadata.

Comment: Ok,bro.Thank you

Comment: Can you share your github repo? I bet lots of others would like to see this working too (who doesn't love more rust?).

Comment: Sure.Here is my [github repo](https://github.com/GinmusWJQ/yew-subxt-demo)

Comment: with `features = ["jsonrpsee-web"]` you won't be able to use the new() or from_url() functions as those only get compiled with `features = ["jsonrpsee-ws"]`. you can check it here https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/b7a29a5efe60f7c21de556f737e486cfcc852cf3/subxt/src/client/online_client.rs#L85

Comment: why are you using `subxt` version `0.27.0` (in the repo link you shared your using `0.25.0` instead of the latest `0.27.1`? why are you using `wasm-bindgen-futures` version `0.4.32` instead of the latest `0.4.34`? why using `wasm-bindgen` version `0.2.82` instead of the latest `0.2.84`?

Comment: note: i just replicated your error using the code in your post here running a node using the latest substrate version and latest rust version even with `subxt` `0.27.1`, `wasm-bindgen-futures` `0.4.34`. i got error `Failed to decode metadata: Could not decode RuntimeMetadataPrefixed.0: Not enough data to fill buffer` and error `no function or associated item named 'new' found for struct 'OnlineClient' in the current scope`

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Build a local blockchain
> 2. run cargo install subxt-cli
> 3. run subxt metadata -f bytes > metadata.scale

How are you building/starting a local blockchain node? The error `error: Failed to decode metadata: Could not decode RuntimeMetadataPrefixed.1` implies that there is something wrong with your `metadata.scale` file.

Perhaps you ran into an error running `subxt metadata -f bytes > metadata.scale` and the file is empty or doesn't have the expected contents in (how big is it? Can you open it with a text editor?). Perhaps the node you started has some sort of issue. I'd need more information to be able to help with this.

> By the way, I find if I don't specify the subxt as subxt = { version="0.27.0", default-features = false, features = ["jsonrpsee-web"] } in my Cargo.toml, it seem like impossible to work with Yew.rs

That's right; the default features enabled in Subxt aren't compatible with compiling it to WASM, since it relies (by default) on Substrate bits and Jsonrpsee bits that themselves don't compile to WASM.

As you've found, `default-features = false, features = ["jsonrpsee-web"]` is required to disable the features which aren't WASM compatible, and then `jsonrpsee-web` provides a WASM (web) compatible RPC client :)

This does need to be better documented, which is something I will be working on much more in the coming months (notably here; documenting common user flows eg using with wasm).

> no function or associated item named `new` found for struct `OnlineClient` in the current scope

The `OnlineClient::new()` method is available in these cases:

```rust
#[cfg(any(
    feature = "jsonrpsee-ws",
    all(feature = "jsonrpsee-web", target_arch = "wasm32")
))]
```

In other words, either the `jsonrpsee-ws` feature needs to be enabled, *or* the `jsonrpsee-web` feature needs to be enabled *and* you're compiling to WASM. My best guess is that you're using the `jsonrpsee-web` feature but not compiling to WASM, though again I'd need more information :)